# Проверка двух массивов

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно проверить `array1` с `array2` по полям `line_id` и `u_id`, если они совпадают то на выходе расширить `array1` добавив туда некоторые поля из `array2`.

Я пытался пробегаться "foreach" по "array1" и подставляя "index", проверять "array2", но этот способ не подошел, т.к. "array2" может приходить с другой сортировкой и тогда проверяемые не подходят по index. Хотя в них присутствуют одинаковые line_idи u_id, но т.к. у array2 изменилась сортировка , проверка не проходит.

```
array1 = [
0 => array:3 [
"line_id" => "1cc6c7634863f0dbeb6c6252e788a276"
"product" => 123
"case" => false]
1 => array:3 [
"line_id" => "59f0fdf1d94b281474937d16f15d7360"
"product" => 456
"case" => 20
```

]
]

```
array2 [
  0 => array:18 [
  "u_id" => "59f0fdf1d94b281474937d16f15d7360"
  "product" => 123
  "case" => false]
  1 => array:18 [
  "u_id" => "1cc6c7634863f0dbeb6c6252e788a276"
  "product" => 456
  "case" => 20
```

]
]

Вот пример как я пробовал:

```
foreach($array2['items'] as $key => $item) {
                if($item['u_id'] == $array2[$key]['line_id']) {
                    $items[$key]['doc'] = $discount['doc'] ?? '';
                    $items[$key]['sale'] = $discount['sale'] ?? 0;
                };
            };
```

это не подходит, т.к. например в обоих массивах есть значение "59f0fdf1d94b281474937d16f15d7360", но в array1 оно находится в массиве с индексом "1", а в array2, с индексом "0", и тогда если{ if ($array2[$key] == $value {....})} в $key будет 0, а в текущей итерации у array1 с индексом 0 в поле row_id находится 1cc6c7634863f0dbeb6c6252e788a276, что не соотвествует 59f0fdf1d94b281474937d16f15d7360 индекса 0 массива array2

Comment: Может попробовать использовать такую форму foreach? `foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) { if ($array2[$key] == $value {....})}` Тут получается что мы берем значение первого массива ($value) , его ключ ($key) подставляем ко второму массиву и если они равны, то дальше делаем то, что вам нужно

Comment: @АлексейМельников, я так пробовал, это не подходит, т.к. например в обоих массивах есть значение "59f0fdf1d94b281474937d16f15d7360", но в array1 оно находится в массиве с индексом "1", а в array2, с индексом "0", и тогда если{ if ($array2[$key] == $value {....})} в $key будет 0, а в текущей итерации у array1  с индексом 0 в поле row_id находится 1cc6c7634863f0dbeb6c6252e788a276, что не соотвествует 59f0fdf1d94b281474937d16f15d7360 индекса 0 массива array2

Comment: таких вопросов миллионы. вытащите нужный индекс в одном из массивов при помощи array_column, а дальше просто по нему берите элементы

Comment: @splash58, можете пожалуйста показать на примере?

Comment: @Dolphin написать за вас код? может, вы хотя бы попробуете. там все в 3-4 оператора должно уложиться

Comment: @splash58, нет код писать не нужно за меня, просто показать, честно говоря не понял как сделать по вашему совету.

Comment: что такое пример? что показать? как вызвать функцию array_column ? откройте документацию. поищите в гугле на том же стэке по названию функции

Comment: @splash58, я знаю как вызвать array_column, например array_column($array1,'row_id'), мне вовзратился массив: array:3 [▼
  0 => "2f3f23cf1d561fbaa31a0a37ed33298d"
  1 => "5545606b0af283d4ae2f286027c6e132"
  2 => "767f1c4fd6aa3dc898812babb5c11d51"
], но далее не это можно применить в моем вопросе? По этому у вас спрашиваю, какая у вас была идея, если не сложно просто покажите, если что закрое вопрос, очень нужно было просто найти грамотное решение.

Comment: я вроде русским языком написал - почитайте документацию. там третий параметр есть - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Научиться решать такие задачи поможет опыт в материальном мире. Возьмём несколько бумажек (офисных стикеров) и на каждой напишем по одному знеачению из массивов. Сложим бумажки в две стопки $array1 и $array2. Как теперь вы бы руками сделали то, что хотите запрограммировать?

Я сейчас напишу как бы поступил я, но не спешите просто копировать моё решение (так вы ничему не научитесь), проделайте опыт сами.

1. берём бумажку из стопки $array1. На ней написано

```
row_id: 1cc6c7634863f0dbeb6c6252e788a276
...
```

2. теперь нам надо **пролистать** стопку $array2, и найти в ней бумажку, на которой написано

```
uniq_id: 1cc6c7634863f0dbeb6c6252e788a276
...
```

3. теперь допишем в бумажку из стопки $array1 doc и sale с найденой бумажки из $array2;
4. переходим к первому шагу.

Порядок бумажек в $array1 и $array2 значения не имеет. Потому что мы каждый раз перебираем бумажки из $array2, чтобы найти подходящую. Получается цикл в цикле.

Этот алгоритм можно улучшить. Например можно убирать из стопки $array2 бумажки, которые уже совпали с бумажками из $array1. Тогда искать в оставщихся бумажках из $array2 будет каждый раз быстрее.

Но есть ещё одна идея. Что если предварительно пролистать всю стопку $array2 и составить справочник какой uniq_id на каком месте в стопке? Теперь на втором шаге нам не надо листать всю стопку $array2. Мы просто смотрим в справочник и достаём нужную бумажку. Роль справочника в php играет ассоциативный массив (почитайте что такое [хэш-таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)).

Comment: спасибо за алгоритмы, цикл в цикле, и то как я выше указал как я делал, понятно. Я просто хотел увидеть как более оптимизированно и грамотно еще можно сделать от более профессионалов :)

Comment: @Dolphin Более оптимально составить справочник (ассоциативный массив) по ключу uiniq_id и заменить вложенный цикл на обращение по ключу.

Comment: Егор Банин, я сейчас сделал так: $sales = []; foreach($arr2 as $key => $item) { $sales[$item['unique_id']] = $item; }; foreach($arr1 as $key => $arrItem) { if (array_search($arrItem['row_id'], $sales[$arrItem['row_id']])) { $arr1[$key]['product'] = $sales[$arrItem['row_id']]['product'] ?? ''; $arr1[$key]['case'] = $sales[$arrItem['row_id']]['case'] ?? 0; }; };

Comment: Прокомментируй пожалуйста своим опытным мнением :)

Comment: @Dolphin вам не нужен array_search (это цикл, просто он спрятан в функцию). Вы можете заменить его `if (isset($sales[$arrItem['row_id']]))`.

Comment: @Dolphin И вам советовали функцию [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php), которая делает то же что ваш первый цикл. `$sales = array_column($arr2, null, 'unique_id');`

Comment: Ребята всем спасибо :)